# Using JFileChooser and File handlng

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, file-handling

I am having trouble of using JFileChooser to open text files and read it in the console, I try to get source codes from some tutorials but I only got codes for "file handling" and "how to use JFileChooser" and I tried to combine them or something just to work out but I cant seem to do it, I'm really running out of ideas, any help will do.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 2):

If the JFileChooser returns `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`, using `.getSelectedFile()` will return a `File` object

```
File file;
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooer();
int returnValue = JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (returnVal = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
}
```

If you understand how to you basic I/O, then you should know what to do with that file.

Something fairly simple would just be something like this

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        textArea.append(line + "\n");
} catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

- Another option is to use the [`JTextComponent#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method
- Another option is to use a [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) and just use its [`setPage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage%28java.lang.String%29) method

  ```
  JEditorPane document = new JEditorPane();

  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  try {
       document.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
  } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

---

If you need basic help with I/O, see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)